# Verificar se a pessoa vai fechar o site

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de verificar se o mouse da pessoa está indo pra fechar o site? Com JavaScript, etc... No caso mais simples:

```
if(estaindofechar){
  alert("Tem certeza?");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse é o método chamado quando o usuário tenta sair da página

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja fechar a página?");
};
```

Comment: Obrigado LuKs, mas tem algum modo do script identificar se o mouse está quase chegando perto de onde o botão de fechar a aba la? Ja vi essa função mas não sei como é feito...

Comment: Nesse caso você tem que implementar um pouco mais de JS, identificando o ponto em que o cursor se encontra na tela